# Checking and filtering the first event of each group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an event dataset. First of all, I grouped my dataset by user_id and location with pandas library. Then I order my each group by created_at. I want to delete all group if the group does not start with 'Open' event.

My dataset:

| user_id | location | event_name | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | AAA | Event5 | 9/1/2020 9:06:52 PM |
| A1 | AAA | Event6 | 9/1/2020 9:07:02 PM |
| A1 | AAA | Open | 9/1/2020 9:07:12 PM |
| A1 | AAA | Event1 | 9/1/2020 9:07:22 PM |
| A1 | AAA | Event2 | 9/1/2020 9:07:32 PM |
| A1 | AAA | Event3 | 9/1/2020 9:07:42 PM |
| A1 | AAA | Event2 | 9/1/2020 9:07:52 PM |
| A1 | AAA | Open | 9/1/2020 9:08:02 PM |
| A1 | AAA | Event1 | 9/1/2020 9:08:12 PM |
| A1 | AAA | Event2 | 9/1/2020 9:08:22 PM |
| A2 | AAA | Event9 | 9/1/2020 9:07:22 PM |

I want:

| user_id | location | event_name | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | AAA | Open | 9/1/2020 9:07:12 PM |
| A1 | AAA | Event1 | 9/1/2020 9:07:22 PM |
| A1 | AAA | Event2 | 9/1/2020 9:07:32 PM |
| A1 | AAA | Event3 | 9/1/2020 9:07:42 PM |
| A1 | AAA | Open | 9/1/2020 9:08:02 PM |
| A1 | AAA | Event1 | 9/1/2020 9:08:12 PM |
| A1 | AAA | Event2 | 9/1/2020 9:08:22 PM |

Thank you.

Comment: from your example it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you give more details please?

Comment: If there is no “open” event before any other event, I want to delete them. I just want to create full event cycle like “open-event x-event y” etc. Each group has start with “open” event.

Answer (score 1):

In short:

```
df[~(df['event_name'] != 'Open').groupby([df['user_id'], df['location']]).cumprod()]
```

Explanation:

`(df['event_name'] != 'Open')` gives us a series of `True`/`False` which can also be understood as `1`/`0` when interpreted as numbers. `cumprod` apply cumulative product to the `True`/`False` series so that as soon as it sees an `False` (i.e. `0` or `'Open'`), it returns a zero and remain zero thereafter.

So we may use zero as the indicator of rows that we wanna to keep.